# I was creating my own palindrome program when I came across that if I use [ ] for 'if' loop, every time it printed the 'if' statement

Tags: python, parentheses

The use of parentheses for 'if' loop results in two different output for a palindrome program!

1.) () this gives the accurate result
2.) [] this only gives you the result of 'if' statement even if the "String" is not a palindrome

```
def isapalindrome(String):
    if(String == String[::-1]):
        return("is a palindrome!")
    
    else:
        return("is not a palindrome!")

String = input("Enter the String of your choice: ")
isapalindrome(String)
```

this code executes properly!

```
def isapalindrome(String):
    if[String == String[::-1]]:
        return("is a palindrome!")
    
    else:
        return("is not a palindrome!")

String = input("Enter the String of your choice: ")
isapalindrome(String)
```

this code executes only the 'if' statement!

Comment: Please put your code between two lines of triple backticks: `\`\`\``

Comment: In Python the condition in an `if` statement doesn't need parentheses at all. `if String == String[::-1]:` is perfectly fine.

Comment: As for your problem, if you have e.g. `a = (b + c)`, would you really think that `a = [b + c]` would be the same thing? What makes you think that? What do you know about ***[lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)*** in Python? And what resource are you using to learn Python?

Comment: If you wrap an expression in `[]`, it creates a list with that expression value as its sole element.  The truth value of a non-empty list is true.

Answer (score 2):

`()` and `[]` are nothing alike.

`()` does what you expect it to, but wouldn't even be necessary since there is only one operator.

`[]` will create a list with a single element that equals the truth value of `String == String[::-1]`, so either `[True]` or `[False]`. Independently of what the list contains, non-empty list in python are truthy. This means that your if condition will always evaluate to `True`

Comment: `[]` will create a list, not an array.  Arrays are a numpy type.  Try `type([])`.  It shows that it's a list, not an array.  It is true that Python lists are "arrays" in a general data structure sense, but the Python terminology calls them lists.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments suggest, the correct structure of an if statement is:

```
if condition:
    print("Do something")
else:
    print("Do nothing")
```

Parenthesis are useful when using boolean expressions:

```
if (A==B) == C:
    print("Do")
```

Point being, the brackets '[ ]' do not really belong there. As they are used to select a memory space within a given memory slot. Just like we would do with arrays.

I think is good that you are exploring different things, it is always good to know why things are the way they are.